# RevoscaleR for SQL Server to fetch data from views

Tags: sql-server, revolution-r

Hi I am using RevoScaleR package  from Revolution Analytics and 

I find it quite odd that the functions that are available for sql server objects are very limited .

for example:

RxSqlServerData does not support querying from a view .

I have a view which I have created from multiple tables and I intend to use this view as my source of data and I could not find anything that can solve my purpose in RevoScaleR .

I can very well create another table ( which I dont want to for many reasons) but I am looking for solutions in RevoScaleR space.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out ,if someone else stumbles upon this ,I guess it would help them(although its highly unlikely ,the documentation ,if consulted,should make this pretty trivial)

Like RxOdbcData ,RxSqlServerData  also accepts table parameter and sqlquery parameter .
Now if you want to use a view or a stored Procedure you can exclude the table parameter and use sqlquery parameter .

keep in mind that both can not be used with each other

Comment: I have a similar problem and found this - thanks! So, just to make sure - this would allow me to set up a `RxSqlServerData` object as a result from the `query` arg supplied, and use it as a starting point for further analysis?

Answer (score 0):

As @Bg1850 suggested - searching through the Microsoft/RevoScaleR docs is not very easy, but I think I found something [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt629161.aspx) under Section : "Create New Data Sources" .

Basically, you have to set up a channel to your DB and you can use this as the basis to define different data sources ( = complete table or view or result of a SQL query).